# How can I test if a String contains the characters of a particular string?

Tags: java, string

I have a `String` with value

```
String rest="bac";
```

I have another `String` with value

```
String str="baack";
```

If i use

```
str.contains(rest);
```

it returns false. But i want the output to be true. As "baack" contains all the letters from `string rest`

Is it possible to do so? With or without this method?

Comment: A `String` is not a "set" of characters, it is "list" of characters, in order.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Do the letters have to be in the same order? What do you want the answer to `"bar".contains("ra")` to be?

Comment: There's no function to do that. Just roll your own code. It's not very difficult. If you face specific problems, just show us your code and we'll help you.

Comment: You can use regex.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: i know. I was just wondering whether its possible to be true even if the characters are not in order. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to write your own function for that. Depending on your specific requirements, maybe you can even use a regex as @Invexity pointed out.

Comment: @pbabcdefp no. they don't have to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no standard method doing this, as far as I know.

If what you want is to check that the second string contains at least once every character of the first string, then you can check each character one by one with the following test:

```
boolean result = true;
for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
    result &= str.indexOf(c) > -1;
}
return result;
```

Or alternatively:

```
for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
    if (str.indexOf(c) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

It might not be optimal, but it works and it is simple to read.

Answer (score 0):

Since the order is not important, your question turns to be whether the first set of character contains the second set of character.

```
// Initial the sets
Set<char> bigSet = new HashSet<char>(Arrays.asList(str)); 
Set<char> smallSet = new HashSet<char>(Arrays.asList(rest)); 

for (char c : smallSet) {
    if(!bigSet.contains(c)){
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to make sure all characters from one string are in the second string. It is a lengthy way but it is one of the very basic ways to work with characters from String in java. I know it is not optimal but it serves the purpose.

```
        String rest="bac";
        String str="baack";
        char[] strChar = str.toCharArray();
        char[] restChar = rest.toCharArray();
        int count = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<restChar.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<strChar.length; j++){
                if(restChar[i] == strChar[j]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(count>=restChar.length){
            System.out.println("All the characters from: "+rest+" are in: "+str);
        }
```